# What is the best way to connect to a Sybase database from Python?

Tags: python, sybase

I am trying to retrieve data in a Sybase data base from Python and I was wondering which would be the best way to do it. I found this module but may be you have some other suggestions:
http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The sybase module you linked is by far the easiest way. You can get data like so:

```
import Sybase

db = Sybase.connect('server','name','pass','database')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("sql statement")
list1 = c.fetchall()

print list1
```

You will have to use something like freetds to setup the interfaces for sybase, however.

Answer (score 0):

you can also connect through [ODBC](http://tinyurl.com/255plm2).

Comment: thanks for your answer! is it faster? i need something fast and some connections are known to have different speeds..

Comment: I suggest you try them out and see for yourself. anyway, "faster" or not depends on alot of things. your sql queries, your network settings etc...

Comment: do you have some sample or document to read ? Iam looking for a easy runable sample

Answer (score 0):

There is also `python-pymssql` which is in Debian / Ubuntu.  This can connect to MS-SQL-Server or Sybase using freetds.  I'm not sure how it compares to the other options.

http://www.pymssql.org/

Example code, abridged from their website:

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect('server','user','pass','database')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=%s', 'John Doe')
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print("ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row[0], row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
conn.close()
```

Comment: when I used it it keeps frozee