# Connect to Sybase data base using Python 3.6 and pymssql

Tags: python-3.x, sybase, pymssql

I am trying to connect to a Sybase database and retrieve data from it. I am working on a Ubuntu 18.04 system with the Anaconda repository installed and would like to use Python 3.6.

I found a way to retrieve data from the DB with the python-sybase package, but this has dependencies on python 2.7 and is kind of outdated as far as I now.

```
import Sybase

db = Sybase.connect(dsn = server:port, user = usr, passwd = pwd, database = db)
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("select var1,var2,var3 from xxx where datum=1yymmdd and statnr=stat1")
list1 = c.fetchall()
print list1
```

The Output of this script is something like this:

```
[(10.8, 100, 0), (11.2, 100, 5), (11.3, 100, 10), ..., ..., ...]
```

I tried to use te pymssql package instead, which is compatible to python 3.x.

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server=serv:port,user=usr,password=pwd,database=db)
print(conn)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select var1,var2,var3 from xxx where datum=1yymmdd and statnr=stat1")
list2 = cursor.fetchall()
print(list2)
```

But get the following error message, already after trying to connect to the Database, as it doesn't do print(conn):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect
File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1957, in _mssql.connect
File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 707, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
_mssql.MSSQLDriverException: Could not set connection properties

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/progs/Test_SYBASE.py", line 9, in <module>
conn =  pymssql.connect(server=serv,user=usr,password=pwd,database=db,port=prt)
File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 645, in pymssql.connect
pymssql.InterfaceError: Could not set connection properties
```

So my problem is actually concerning the connection itself.

I read about the error message in the pymssql manual but don't know how to handle this.

> exception _mssql.MSSQLDriverException
>   MSSQLDriverException is raised whenever there is a problem within _mssql – e.g. insufficient memory for data structures, and so on.
>
> exception pymssql.InterfaceError
>   Raised for errors that are related to the database interface rather than the database itself. A subclass of Error.

Do you have any suggestion how to handle this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to connect to a sybase database from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319788/what-is-the-best-way-to-connect-to-a-sybase-database-from-python)

Comment: @GordThompson thank you for linking the other question post, I read it before posting my question but it doesn't seem to work for me. I edited my above post slightly to be more clear about the problem I have. As I understand I have a problem building the connection, it doesn't even start the readout. It's strange because using the python-sybase module works fine with the exact same login variables...

Comment: [This comment on GitHub](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/339#issuecomment-165740512) suggests that you might be able to add `conn_properties=''` to your `pymssql.connect` call. Still, since pymssql is really not designed to support Sybase (just MS SQL), I'd be inclined to use pyodbc and FreeTDS_ODBC instead of pymssql.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I managed to use pyodbc and FreeTDS to connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem:
As suggested by @GordThompson I used pyodbc and FreeTDS to connect. 
I installed the FreeTDS driver via

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin unixodbc-dev tdsodbc
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tdsodbc
```

as suggested here: https://gist.github.com/rduplain/1293636

My code to connect looks like that:

```
import pyodbc
serv = server
usr = user 
passwd = password
db = database
prt = port
driver="FreeTDS"

conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=serv, database=db,port = prt,
                  uid=usr, pwd=passwd)
print(conn)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select var1,var2,var3 from xxx where datum=1yymmdd and statnr=stat1")
row = cursor.fetchall()
print(row)
```

EDIT: using conn_properties = '' in my pymssql.connect() call works as well, just as @GordThompson suggested.

```
import pymssql
conn =pymssql.connect(server=serv:port,user=usr,password=pwd,database=db, conn_properties='')
print(conn)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select var1,var2,var3 from xxx where datum=1yymmdd and statnr=stat1")
list2 = cursor.fetchall()
print(list2)
```

Thanks for your help!